# Codekit not compiling scss files when using compass

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, codekit, compass

my compass version is 1.0.1 (Polaris)
my sass version is 3.4.5

when I do a normal `compass watch` it works just fine.  I love using codekit and I want it compile my scss files but it is not and its driving me nuts.

If any body has any ideas on how to fix this pleas let me know. Thanks in advance.

Here is my error when trying to compile:
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in`fu_mkdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in`reverse_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in`each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in`write_gem_make_out'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in`rescue in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in`block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in`build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in`use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in`build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in`block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in`try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in`'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in`'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass.rb:13:in`each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in`require'
    from /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/compass/bin/compass:41:in `block in <main>'
    from /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/compass/bin/compass:29:in`fallback_load_path'
    from /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/compass/bin/compass:40:in `'

Answer (score 2):

It was right after I had upgraded to Yosemite that compass started failing for me, after I ran

```
> sudo gem update
```

it worked. compass was one of the packages it updated.

I think Codekit allows you to choose which compiler you want to use, either the the internal Codekit one or the system one. My coworker, who uses Codekit with Codekits internal Compass compiler, didn't have an issue, but I use the system compass compiler and that was failing.

I'm not sure what changed, in the packages or permissions or the system settings